# Why am I getting this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nst_utils'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am getting this error after running this line of codes to import libraries for implementing a neural style algorithm:

```
import os
import sys
import scipy.io
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from PIL import Image
from nst_utils import *
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a copy of *nst_utils.py*?

It is part of the work done when going through **deeplearning.ai**'s Deep Learning specialization online course, specifically [Week 4 of Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks). You need to have a copy of *nst_utils.py* in the same directory as that code you're running (or that it's added to your sys.path).

If you do a search for *nst_utils.py*, you'll get some links to github repositories of people who went through the course, and posted their work online, like this: https://github.com/JudasDie/deeplearning.ai. You could probably copy their *nst_utils.py* code (check their README for usage and license notes), though it would have been better if you went through the course yourself.